# How to validate OAuth state on redirect

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, csrf

I think I am misunderstanding the OAuth OpenID Connect specification and here's why:

I try to implement "Sign in with Apple". You can opt to use a popup or a redirect to an apple page I want to keep it simple at first, so I am using the redirect options. Clicking the "Sign in with Apple" button will redirect me to the apple sign in page having the `state` filled to prevent CSRF attacks.

After successful authentication, apple "redirects" to my specified redirect url by making a POST request to that URL with the `state`, `code` and `id_token` value.

Now here's the thing: How am I supposed to validate the state, when the POST request originated from a different session? I send a CSRF-Token as the `state` from the user who clicked on the "Sign in with Apple" button but the response from apple was made as a different session – having a different CSRF-Token.

Am I even supposed to validate the state in this kind of flow? I feel that I have to otherwise someone could just use CSRF to send a POST request to my redirect URL with an arbitrary `code` and `id_token`.

Anyone knows how to validate the `state`? I'd appreciate the help :D Thanks in advance.

---

Addition: With the popup option everything should work, I receive `state`, `code` and `id_token` in a browser event after successful authentication so I can validate that the `state` and the `nonce` both match.

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone knows how to validate the state?

It's client responsibility to validate the state to prevent against the `CSRF` attack. So, client must generate some state value, store it in the available storages (cookies, session, or localstorage) on its side. Pass it to the auth server. Post auth, control is redirected back from auth server to client. Now, client can retrieve the state parameter and compare it with one stored earlier. If values don't match, terminate the flow.

Comment: But how can I identify the client? Apple POSTs to the redirect URL resulting in a completely different session. I inspected some libraries implementing OAuth OpenID Connect flows and they expect a GET redirect to the URL. This way I could validate the state.